# In a double buffer opengl context, is it possible that front and back buffer be the same?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, opengl, nsview

I have a situation in which I ask and get a double-buffering OpenGL context, but when I draw in it, both the front and back buffer are affected. The draw buffer is set to the back buffer (And only the back buffer). If I look in OpenGL Profiler, I do see all that: the value for GL_DRAW_BUFFER (GL_BACK) and the actual back and front buffer being drawn to.

Since I'm working with an NSWindow that has a backing store, We do not see any of this happening on the screen. The problem is that I'm getting screenshots of this window with CGWindowListCreateImage. This function seems to be fetching the image from the front buffer, and not from the screen buffer (Wherever that is...). So the image returned is incomplete: it only contains the elements that are drawn at the moment it is grabbed, even if no flush has been called.

There is a utility in the mac developer package called Pixie. It basically grab the screen at the mouse position, and display it zoomed in so you can analyze it. This program has the same behavior than calling CGWindowListCreateImage: you can see incomplete images. So I guess the problem is not with the way I use CGWindowListCreateImage, but rather with my window or my display...

Also, It does not seems to happen all the time. Not every windows show this behavior, and even for a given window, it seems to come and go, especially if I move the window to a different screen (In a dual display).

Anyone faced this before?

Comment: Could you be unintentionally swapping the buffers somewhere?

Comment: I put a breakpoint before and after a call to glDrawArrays, and the effect is immediate. It's been one of my first guesses.

Comment: MacOS X Cocoa / Quartz Extreme is essentially a compositing window management system. Compositing Window management in some way lifts the need for per-window-double buffering since whatever is drawn to the window goes through a second drawing stage (the compositing). I'm now wildly guessing: It could very will be, that in MacOS X a double buffered window is in fact just recieving a single buffer and the doublebuffering swap used for synchronization with the compositor.

Comment: datenwolf: I don't think this is the case, cause normally, I don't see this behavior.